# GlassFish - Admin console deploy at startup

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3, asadmin

This is a simple question: is there a way to tell GlassFish to load & deploy admin console during startup and not on-demand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the admin console, go to the "Domain"view. There a checkbox labeled
**Load console after DAS startup**. Make sure it's checked. Don't forget to save, now the admin console will be loaded automatically instead of on the first access.

You can also use the asadmin utility to change this setting:

`asadmin set configs.config.server-config.admin-service.property.adminConsoleStartup=ALWAYS`

Comment: Thanks for this reply, even if it is a really old question. It's a really annoying issue and somehow I did not noticed this option yet.

Comment: @GaborGarami as these instructions still work with GF4 it was worth answering such an old question, I'm happy it helped you!